# How to download multiple files in multiple sub-directories using curl?

Tags: bash, curl, wget

I am downloading multiple files using curl. The base URL for all the files is the same like

https://mydata.gov/daily/2017

The data in these directories are further grouped by date and file type. So the first data that I need has this directory

https://mydata.gov/daily/2017/001/17d/Roger001.gz

The second data being

https://mydata.gov/daily/2017/002/17d/Roger002.gz

I need to download up until the data for the last day of 2017 which is

https://mydata.gov/daily/2017/365/17d/Roger365.gz

How can I use curl or any other similar tool to download all the files to a single local folder, preferably adopting the original file names?

Comment: What have you tried? Would `for f in {001..365}; do curl https://mydata.gov/daily/2017/001/17d/Roger"$f".gz; done` work?

Comment: @jared_mamrot what troubles me is that the middle part of the directory changes for every file. For an instance data for the first day has 2017/001 in the middle while for the 2nd day it will be 2017/002.

Comment: Looks like @mjrezaee has the right command in that case - did that work for you?

Comment: Yes! It does work. Still thanks for your comment in this question! It also helps. @jared_mamrot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `for f in {001..365}; do curl https://mydata.gov/daily/2017/"$f"/17d/Roger"$f".gz -o /your-directory/Roger"$f".gz; done` in bash terminal.
replace `your-directory` with your directory which you want to save files.

Comment: Hi @mjrezaee your answer somehow works but with some problem. I found out that some files were not downloaded successfully. There were output files but with nothing inside them, 0 kb in file size. I tried executing the command again but another set of files are lacking. I tried executing the command multiple times and the results are random sets of the files being downloaded correctly while leaving others empty.

Comment: I think I found out the problem. I used -O instead of -o thinking that it would automatically copy the file name from the remote location but this seems to cause the problem. Your answer works perfectly well. Thanks!